# Show long cross hair cursor over image performance bad

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I load a 3840x2160 image with below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
import matplotlib.patches as patches

class SnaptoCursor(object):
    def __init__(self, ax):
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx = ax.axhline(color='r')  # the horiz line
        self.ly = ax.axvline(color='r')  # the vert line
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        # update the line positions
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.draw()

img = image.imread("exam.jpg") #3840x2160
fig,ax =plt.subplots(1)
ax.imshow(img)

snap_cursor = SnaptoCursor(ax)
fig.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', snap_cursor.mouse_move)

plt.show()
```

When I move the mouse, I can see the long crosshair cursor (two line actually) move very slow. I wish it move with the cursor immediately.

Welcome if any other good solution!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are redrawing the entire canvas every time the mouse moves, this is unnecessary - you simply need to redraw the two artists and use blitting to avoid redrawing the rest. This is slightly tricky when there is something behind the relevant artists (i.e. an image or colormesh). Something like this should suffice:

```py
class SnaptoCursor(object):
    def __init__(self, ax):
        # Have to draw the canvas once beforehand to cache the renderer
        ax.figure.canvas.draw()
        self.bg = ax.figure.canvas.copy_from_bbox(ax.bbox)
        self.ax = ax
        self.lx = ax.axhline(color='r')  # the horiz line
        self.ly = ax.axvline(color='r')  # the vert line
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def mouse_move(self, event):
        if not event.inaxes:
            return
        x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
        # update the line positions
        ax.figure.canvas.restore_region(self.bg)
        self.lx.set_ydata(y)
        self.ly.set_xdata(x)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.lx)
        self.ax.draw_artist(self.ly)
        self.ax.figure.canvas.blit(self.ax.bbox)
```

Although adjustments may be required depending on the backend etc.

Comment: It return a error when I move mouse: TypeError: restore_region() argument 1 must be matplotlib.backends._backend_agg.BufferRegion, not method, maybe backend not correct? I am using matplotlib.use('MacOSX')

Comment: @lucky1928 There was a typo, `self.bg` was pointing to the method - I intended to call the method. Try it with the above correction

Comment: Sounds like performance still the same, the lines update later almost 0.5s after mouse moved to a new positon. btw, blit line changed to self.ax.figure.canvas.blit(ax.bbox).

Comment: @lucky1928 You can try without the `ax.figure.canvas.restore_region` line - it is only necessary for some backends

Comment: @lucky1928 This is significantly faster for me with the `TkAgg`, `Qt5Agg`, and `GTK3Agg` backends - perhaps try one of those

Comment: Yes, try TkAgg and it's faster, but the old one still exist so after mouse move, full of red lines on my picture! Maybe it's macosx issue!

Comment: @lucky1928 That is odd... perhaps it is a bug, I will investigate

Comment: @lucky1928 I figured it out: the canvas has to be drawn once beforehand in order to cache the renderer. Try the edited version above - should work correctly.